# Receiving "Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected" when performing 'yum history undo'

Tags: centos, yum

We have a Centos 6.10 machine on i686 architecture. The server is running old software that requires specific versions of certain packages.

We have had to restart a machine for the first time since 2016 and have realised that an update that was performed in 2020 has broken the start-up procedure for old software running on this server.

So, we're currently trying to perform a `yum history undo` for a transaction that altered just over 200 packages in 2020 which should get us back to a workable confirmed state for this old software.

Here is the `yum history` output:

```
ID | Login user | Date and time    | Action(s) | Altered
-------------------------------------------------------------
35 | redacted   | 2023-04-07 10:09 | Erase     |   14
34 | redacted   | 2023-04-07 10:08 | Erase     |    1
33 | redacted   | 2023-04-07 10:08 | Erase     |    2
32 | redacted   | 2020-09-25 13:11 | Install   |    2
31 | redacted   | 2020-09-22 11:19 | Install   |    1
30 | redacted   | 2020-06-29 14:49 | Install   |   14
29 | redacted   | 2020-04-30 20:17 | E, I, U   |  203 E<
28 | redacted   | 2014-09-26 07:58 | Update    |    1 >
```

As you can see, we've already undone transaction 32, 31 and 30. We're now trying to do 29, which is a much larger update. Unfortunately, we are receiving the following once all of the dependency resolution is performed.

`Error: Trying to remove "yum", which is protected`

As this is a reversal of a transaction that was performed, I assume that yum is actually just being downgraded, not removed, but that the dependency resolution hasn't worked this out.

My other worry is that, given this is a large update that is attempting to be rolled back, whether there's a likelihood of introducing further problems, or whether yum is quite reliable at backing out of even large transactions.

If anyone with some experience of this could help, that would be really appreciated. I've included the full `yum transaction info` below:

```
Packages Altered:
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
Updated     acl-2.2.49-6.el6.i686                                
Update          2.2.49-7.el6_9.1.i686                            
Updated     audit-2.2-2.el6.i686                                 
Update            2.4.5-6.el6.i686                               
Updated     audit-libs-2.2-2.el6.i686                            
Update                 2.4.5-6.el6.i686                          
Updated     authconfig-6.1.12-13.el6.i686                        
Update                 6.1.12-23.el6.i686                        
Updated     bash-4.1.2-15.el6_5.2.i686                           
Update           4.1.2-48.el6.i686                               
Updated     bfa-firmware-3.0.3.1-1.el6.noarch                    
Update                   3.2.23.0-2.el6.noarch                   
Updated     binutils-2.20.51.0.2-5.36.el6.i686                   
Update               2.20.51.0.2-5.48.el6_10.1.i686              
Updated     ca-certificates-2010.63-3.el6_1.5.noarch             
Update                      2019.2.32-65.1.el6_10.noarch         
Updated     centos-release-6-4.el6.centos.10.i686                
Update                     6-10.el6.centos.12.3.i686             
Updated     chkconfig-1.3.49.3-2.el6_4.1.i686                    
Update                1.3.49.5-1.el6.i686                        
Updated     cifs-utils-4.8.1-18.el6.i686                         
Update                 4.8.1-20.el6.i686                         
Updated     coreutils-8.4-19.el6_4.2.i686                        
Update                8.4-47.el6.i686                            
Updated     coreutils-libs-8.4-19.el6_4.2.i686                   
Update                     8.4-47.el6.i686                       
Updated     cpio-2.10-11.el6_3.i686                              
Update           2.10-13.el6.i686                                
Updated     cpp-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                                 
Update          4.4.7-23.el6.i686                                
Updated     cryptsetup-luks-1.2.0-7.el6.i686                     
Update                      1.2.0-11.el6.i686                    
Updated     cryptsetup-luks-libs-1.2.0-7.el6.i686                
Update                           1.2.0-11.el6.i686               
Updated     curl-7.19.7-37.el6_4.i686                            
Update           7.19.7-54.el6_10.i686                           
Updated     cyrus-sasl-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686                    
Update                 2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.i686                    
Updated     cyrus-sasl-devel-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686              
Update                       2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.i686              
Updated     cyrus-sasl-lib-2.1.23-13.el6_3.1.i686                
Update                     2.1.23-15.el6_6.2.i686                
Updated     db4-4.7.25-18.el6_4.i686                             
Update          4.7.25-22.el6.i686                               
Updated     db4-utils-4.7.25-18.el6_4.i686                       
Update                4.7.25-22.el6.i686                         
Updated     dbus-libs-1:1.2.24-7.el6_3.i686                      
Update                1:1.2.24-11.el6_10.i686                    
Updated     device-mapper-1.02.77-9.el6_4.3.i686                 
Update                    1.02.117-12.el6_9.1.i686               
Updated     device-mapper-event-1.02.77-9.el6_4.3.i686           
Update                          1.02.117-12.el6_9.1.i686         
Updated     device-mapper-event-libs-1.02.77-9.el6_4.3.i686      
Update                               1.02.117-12.el6_9.1.i686    
Updated     device-mapper-libs-1.02.77-9.el6_4.3.i686            
Update                         1.02.117-12.el6_9.1.i686          
Updated     device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-64.el6_4.2.i686        
Update                              0.4.9-106.el6_10.1.i686      
Updated     device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-64.el6_4.2.i686   
Update                                   0.4.9-106.el6_10.1.i686 
Updated     device-mapper-persistent-data-0.1.4-1.el6.i686       
Update                                    0.6.2-0.2.rc7.el6.i686 
Updated     dhclient-12:4.1.1-34.P1.el6_4.1.i686                 
Update               12:4.1.1-63.P1.el6.centos.i686              
Updated     dhcp-common-12:4.1.1-34.P1.el6_4.1.i686              
Update                  12:4.1.1-63.P1.el6.centos.i686           
Updated     dracut-004-303.el6.noarch                            
Update             004-411.el6.noarch                            
Updated     dracut-kernel-004-303.el6.noarch                     
Update                    004-411.el6.noarch                     
Updated     dracut-network-004-303.el6.noarch                    
Update                     004-411.el6.noarch                    
Updated     e2fsprogs-1.41.12-14.el6_4.4.i686                    
Update                1.41.12-24.el6.i686                        
Updated     e2fsprogs-libs-1.41.12-14.el6_4.4.i686               
Update                     1.41.12-24.el6.i686                   
Updated     efibootmgr-0.5.4-10.el6.i686                         
Update                 0.5.4-15.el6.i686                         
Updated     elfutils-libelf-0.152-1.el6.i686                     
Update                      0.164-2.el6.i686                     
Updated     ethtool-2:3.5-1.el6.i686                             
Update              2:3.5-6.el6.i686                             
Updated     expat-2.0.1-11.el6_2.i686                            
Update            2.0.1-13.el6_8.i686                            
Updated     fcoe-utils-1.0.24-2.el6.i686                         
Update                 1.0.28-6.el6.i686                         
Updated     file-5.04-15.el6.i686                                
Update           5.04-30.el6.i686                                
Updated     file-libs-5.04-15.el6.i686                           
Update                5.04-30.el6.i686                           
Updated     findutils-1:4.4.2-6.el6.i686                         
Update                1:4.4.2-9.el6.i686                         
Updated     gawk-3.1.7-10.el6.i686                               
Update           3.1.7-10.el6_7.3.i686                           
Updated     gcc-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                                 
Update          4.4.7-23.el6.i686                                
Updated     gcc-c++-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                             
Update              4.4.7-23.el6.i686                            
Updated     gdbm-1.8.0-36.el6.i686                               
Update           1.8.0-39.el6.i686                               
Updated     glib2-2.22.5-7.el6.i686                              
Update            2.28.8-10.el6.i686                             
Updated     glibc-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.i686                        
Update            2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.i686                       
Updated     glibc-common-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.i686                 
Update                   2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.i686                
Updated     glibc-devel-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.i686                  
Update                  2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.i686                 
Updated     glibc-headers-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.i686                
Update                    2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.i686               
Updated     gmp-4.3.1-7.el6_2.2.i686                             
Update          4.3.1-13.el6.i686                                
Updated     gnupg2-2.0.14-6.el6_4.i686                           
Update             2.0.14-9.el6_10.i686                          
Updated     grep-2.6.3-3.el6.i686                                
Update           2.20-6.el6.i686                                 
Updated     grub-1:0.97-81.el6.i686                              
Update           1:0.97-99.el6.i686                              
Updated     grubby-7.0.15-3.el6.i686                             
Update             7.0.15-7.el6.i686                             
Updated     gzip-1.3.12-19.el6_4.i686                            
Update           1.3.12-24.el6.i686                              
Updated     hwdata-0.233-7.9.el6.noarch                          
Update             0.233-20.1.el6.noarch                         
Updated     initscripts-9.03.38-1.el6.centos.2.i686              
Update                  9.03.61-1.el6.centos.i686                
Updated     iproute-2.6.32-23.el6.i686                           
Update              2.6.32-57.el6.i686                           
Updated     iptables-1.4.7-9.el6.i686                            
Update               1.4.7-19.el6.i686                           
Updated     iptables-ipv6-1.4.7-9.el6.i686                       
Update                    1.4.7-19.el6.i686                      
Updated     iputils-20071127-17.el6_4.2.i686                     
Update              20071127-24.el6.i686                         
Updated     iscsi-initiator-utils-6.2.0.873-2.el6.i686           
Update                            6.2.0.873-27.el6_9.i686        
    Erase       kernel-2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.i686                       
    Install     kernel-2.6.32-754.29.1.el6.i686                      
    Erase       kernel-devel-2.6.32-220.7.1.el6.i686                 
    Install     kernel-devel-2.6.32-754.29.1.el6.i686                
Updated     kernel-firmware-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.noarch           
Update                      2.6.32-754.29.1.el6.noarch           
Updated     kernel-headers-2.6.32-358.23.2.el6.i686              
Update                     2.6.32-754.29.1.el6.i686              
Updated     keyutils-1.4-4.el6.i686                              
Update               1.4-5.el6.i686                              
Updated     keyutils-libs-1.4-4.el6.i686                         
Update                    1.4-5.el6.i686                         
Updated     kpartx-0.4.9-64.el6_4.2.i686                         
Update             0.4.9-106.el6_10.1.i686                       
Updated     krb5-libs-1.10.3-10.el6_4.6.i686                     
Update                1.10.3-65.el6.i686                         
Updated     less-436-10.el6.i686                                 
Update           436-13.el6.i686                                 
Updated     libacl-2.2.49-6.el6.i686                             
Update             2.2.49-7.el6_9.1.i686                         
Updated     libblkid-2.17.2-12.9.el6_4.3.i686                    
Update               2.17.2-12.28.el6_9.2.i686                   
Updated     libcgroup-0.37-7.2.el6_4.i686                        
Update                0.40.rc1-27.el6_10.i686                    
Updated     libcom_err-1.41.12-14.el6_4.4.i686                   
Update                 1.41.12-24.el6.i686                       
Updated     libcurl-7.19.7-37.el6_4.i686                         
Update              7.19.7-54.el6_10.i686                        
Updated     libdrm-2.4.39-1.el6.i686                             
Update             2.4.65-2.el6.i686                             
Updated     libgcc-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                              
Update             4.4.7-23.el6.i686                             
Updated     libgcrypt-1.4.5-11.el6_4.i686                        
Update                1.4.5-12.el6_8.i686                        
Updated     libgomp-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                             
Update              4.4.7-23.el6.i686                            
Updated     libhbaapi-2.2.6-1.el6.i686                           
Update                2.2.9-2.el6.i686                           
Updated     libhbalinux-1.0.14-1.el6.i686                        
Update                  1.0.17-2.el6.i686                        
Updated     libnih-1.0.1-7.el6.i686                              
Update             1.0.1-8.el6.i686                              
Updated     libnl-1.1.4-1.el6_4.i686                             
Update            1.1.4-2.el6.i686                               
    Dep-Install libnl3-3.2.21-8.el6.i686                             
Updated     libpciaccess-0.13.1-2.el6.i686                       
Update                   0.13.4-1.el6.i686                       
Updated     libselinux-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686                   
Update                 2.0.94-7.el6.i686                         
Updated     libselinux-utils-2.0.94-5.3.el6_4.1.i686             
Update                       2.0.94-7.el6.i686                   
Updated     libsemanage-2.0.43-4.2.el6.i686                      
Update                  2.0.43-5.1.el6.i686                      
Updated     libss-1.41.12-14.el6_4.4.i686                        
Update            1.41.12-24.el6.i686                            
Updated     libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6.i686                             
Update              1.4.2-3.el6_10.1.i686                        
Updated     libstdc++-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                           
Update                4.4.7-23.el6.i686                          
Updated     libstdc++-devel-4.4.7-3.el6.i686                     
Update                      4.4.7-23.el6.i686                    
Updated     libtalloc-2.0.7-2.el6.i686                           
Update                2.1.5-1.el6_7.i686                         
    Dep-Install libtasn1-2.3-6.el6_5.i686                            
Updated     libtdb-1.2.10-1.el6.i686                             
Update             1.3.8-3.el6_8.2.i686                          
    Dep-Install libtevent-0.9.26-2.el6_7.i686                        
Updated     libtirpc-0.2.1-6.el6_4.i686                          
Update               0.2.1-15.el6.i686                           
Updated     libudev-147-2.46.el6.i686                            
Update              147-2.74.el6_10.i686                         
Updated     libuser-0.56.13-5.el6.i686                           
Update              0.56.13-8.el6_7.i686                         
Updated     libuuid-2.17.2-12.9.el6_4.3.i686                     
Update              2.17.2-12.28.el6_9.2.i686                    
Updated     libxml2-2.7.6-12.el6_4.1.i686                        
Update              2.7.6-21.el6_8.1.i686                        
Updated     lldpad-0.9.45-7.el6.i686                             
Update             0.9.46-10.el6_8.i686                          
Updated     lldpad-libs-0.9.45-7.el6.i686                        
Update                  0.9.46-10.el6_8.i686                     
Updated     logrotate-3.7.8-16.el6.i686                          
Update                3.7.8-28.el6.i686                          
Updated     logwatch-7.3.6-49.el6.noarch                         
Update               7.3.6-55.el6.noarch                         
Updated     lvm2-2.02.98-9.el6_4.3.i686                          
Update           2.02.143-12.el6_9.1.i686                        
Updated     lvm2-libs-2.02.98-9.el6_4.3.i686                     
Update                2.02.143-12.el6_9.1.i686                   
Updated     mailx-12.4-6.el6.i686                                
Update            12.4-10.el6_10.i686                            
Updated     make-1:3.81-20.el6.i686                              
Update           1:3.81-23.el6.i686                              
Updated     mlocate-0.22.2-4.el6.i686                            
Update              0.22.2-6.el6.i686                            
Updated     module-init-tools-3.9-21.el6_4.i686                  
Update                        3.9-26.el6.i686                    
Updated     ncurses-5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686                      
Update              5.7-4.20090207.el6.i686                      
Updated     ncurses-base-5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686                 
Update                   5.7-4.20090207.el6.i686                 
Updated     ncurses-libs-5.7-3.20090208.el6.i686                 
Update                   5.7-4.20090207.el6.i686                 
Updated     net-tools-1.60-110.el6_2.i686                        
Update                1.60-114.el6.i686                          
Updated     newt-0.52.11-3.el6.i686                              
Update           0.52.11-4.el6.i686                              
Updated     newt-python-0.52.11-3.el6.i686                       
Update                  0.52.11-4.el6.i686                       
Updated     nfs-utils-1:1.2.3-36.el6.i686                        
Update                1:1.2.3-78.el6_10.2.i686                   
Updated     nfs-utils-lib-1.1.5-6.el6.i686                       
Update                    1.1.5-13.el6.i686                      
Updated     nscd-2.12-1.107.el6_4.5.i686                         
Update           2.12-1.212.el6_10.3.i686                        
Updated     nspr-4.9.5-2.el6_4.i686                              
Update           4.21.0-1.el6_10.i686                            
Updated     nss-3.14.3-4.el6_4.i686                              
Update          3.44.0-7.el6_10.i686                             
Updated     nss-pam-ldapd-0.7.5-18.2.el6_4.i686                  
Update                    0.7.5-32.el6_10.1.i686                 
Updated     nss-softokn-3.14.3-3.el6_4.i686                      
Update                  3.44.0-6.el6_10.i686                     
Updated     nss-softokn-freebl-3.14.3-3.el6_4.i686               
Update                         3.44.0-6.el6_10.i686              
Updated     nss-sysinit-3.14.3-4.el6_4.i686                      
Update                  3.44.0-7.el6_10.i686                     
Updated     nss-tools-3.14.3-4.el6_4.i686                        
Update                3.44.0-7.el6_10.i686                       
Updated     nss-util-3.14.3-3.el6_4.i686                         
Update               3.44.0-1.el6_10.i686                        
Updated     ntp-4.2.4p8-3.el6.centos.i686                        
Update          4.2.6p5-15.el6.centos.i686                       
Updated     ntpdate-4.2.4p8-3.el6.centos.i686                    
Update              4.2.6p5-15.el6.centos.i686                   
Updated     openldap-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686                      
Update               2.4.40-16.el6.i686                          
Updated     openldap-clients-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686              
Update                       2.4.40-16.el6.i686                  
Updated     openldap-devel-2.4.23-32.el6_4.1.i686                
Update                     2.4.40-16.el6.i686                    
Updated     openssh-5.3p1-84.1.el6.i686                          
Update              5.3p1-124.el6_10.i686                        
Updated     openssh-clients-5.3p1-84.1.el6.i686                  
Update                      5.3p1-124.el6_10.i686                
Updated     openssh-server-5.3p1-84.1.el6.i686                   
Update                     5.3p1-124.el6_10.i686                 
Updated     openssl-1.0.0-27.el6_4.2.i686                        
Update              1.0.1e-58.el6_10.i686                        
    Dep-Install p11-kit-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.i686                        
    Dep-Install p11-kit-trust-0.18.5-2.el6_5.2.i686                  
Updated     pam-1.1.1-13.el6.i686                                
Update          1.1.1-24.el6.i686                                
Updated     passwd-0.77-4.el6_2.2.i686                           
Update             0.77-7.el6.i686                               
Updated     pciutils-libs-3.1.10-2.el6.i686                      
Update                    3.1.10-4.el6.i686                      
Updated     pcre-7.8-6.el6.i686                                  
Update           7.8-7.el6.i686                                  
Updated     perl-4:5.10.1-131.el6_4.i686                         
Update           4:5.10.1-144.el6.i686                           
Updated     perl-Module-Pluggable-1:3.90-131.el6_4.i686          
Update                            1:3.90-144.el6.i686            
Updated     perl-Pod-Escapes-1:1.04-131.el6_4.i686               
Update                       1:1.04-144.el6.i686                 
Updated     perl-Pod-Simple-1:3.13-131.el6_4.i686                
Update                      1:3.13-144.el6.i686                  
Updated     perl-libs-4:5.10.1-131.el6_4.i686                    
Update                4:5.10.1-144.el6.i686                      
Updated     perl-version-3:0.77-131.el6_4.i686                   
Update                   3:0.77-144.el6.i686                     
Updated     pinentry-0.7.6-6.el6.i686                            
Update               0.7.6-8.el6.i686                            
Updated     plymouth-0.8.3-27.el6.centos.i686                    
Update               0.8.3-29.el6.centos.i686                    
Updated     plymouth-core-libs-0.8.3-27.el6.centos.i686          
Update                         0.8.3-29.el6.centos.i686          
Updated     plymouth-scripts-0.8.3-27.el6.centos.i686            
Update                       0.8.3-29.el6.centos.i686            
Updated     policycoreutils-2.0.83-19.30.el6.i686                
Update                      2.0.83-30.1.el6_8.i686               
Updated     procps-3.2.8-25.el6.i686                             
Update             3.2.8-45.el6_9.3.i686                         
Updated     psmisc-22.6-15.el6_0.1.i686                          
Update             22.6-24.el6.i686                              
Updated     python-2.6.6-37.el6_4.i686                           
Update             2.6.6-68.el6_10.i686                          
    Dep-Install python-argparse-1.2.1-2.1.el6.noarch                 
Updated     python-libs-2.6.6-37.el6_4.i686                      
Update                  2.6.6-68.el6_10.i686                     
Updated     python-pycurl-7.19.0-8.el6.i686                      
Update                    7.19.0-9.el6.i686                      
Updated     python-urlgrabber-3.9.1-8.el6.noarch                 
Update                        3.9.1-11.el6.noarch                
Updated     ql2400-firmware-5.08.00-1.el6.noarch                 
Update                      7.03.00-1.el6_5.noarch               
Updated     ql2500-firmware-5.08.00-1.el6.noarch                 
Update                      7.03.00-1.el6_5.noarch               
Updated     rpcbind-0.2.0-11.el6.i686                            
Update              0.2.0-16.el6.i686                            
Updated     rpm-4.8.0-32.el6.i686                                
Update          4.8.0-59.el6.i686                                
Updated     rpm-libs-4.8.0-32.el6.i686                           
Update               4.8.0-59.el6.i686                           
Updated     rpm-python-4.8.0-32.el6.i686                         
Update                 4.8.0-59.el6.i686                         
Updated     rsyslog-5.8.10-7.el6_4.i686                          
Update              5.8.10-12.el6.i686                           
Updated     samba-common-3.6.9-151.el6_4.1.i686                  
Update                   3.6.23-53.el6_10.i686                   
Updated     samba-winbind-3.6.9-151.el6_4.1.i686                 
Update                    3.6.23-53.el6_10.i686                  
Updated     samba-winbind-clients-3.6.9-151.el6_4.1.i686         
Update                            3.6.23-53.el6_10.i686          
Updated     selinux-policy-3.7.19-195.el6_4.18.noarch            
Update                     3.7.19-312.el6.noarch                 
Updated     selinux-policy-targeted-3.7.19-195.el6_4.18.noarch   
Update                              3.7.19-312.el6.noarch        
Updated     setup-2.8.14-20.el6_4.1.noarch                       
Update            2.8.14-23.el6.noarch                           
Updated     shadow-utils-2:4.1.4.2-13.el6.i686                   
Update                   2:4.1.5.1-5.el6.i686                    
    Dep-Install shared-mime-info-0.70-6.el6.i686                     
Updated     sqlite-3.6.20-1.el6.i686                             
Update             3.6.20-1.el6_7.2.i686                         
Updated     strace-4.5.19-1.17.el6.i686                          
Update             4.8-11.el6.i686                               
Updated     sudo-1.8.6p3-7.el6.i686                              
Update           1.8.6p3-29.el6_10.3.i686                        
Updated     system-config-firewall-base-1.2.27-5.el6.noarch      
Update                                  1.2.27-7.2.el6_6.noarch  
Updated     sysvinit-tools-2.87-4.dsf.el6.i686                   
Update                     2.87-6.dsf.el6.i686                   
Updated     tar-2:1.23-11.el6.i686                               
Update          2:1.23-15.el6_8.i686                             
Updated     tcp_wrappers-libs-7.6-57.el6.i686                    
Update                        7.6-58.el6.i686                    
Updated     telnet-1:0.17-47.el6_3.1.i686                        
Update             1:0.17-49.el6_10.i686                         
Updated     tree-1.5.3-2.el6.i686                                
Update           1.5.3-3.el6.i686                                
Updated     tzdata-2013g-1.el6.noarch                            
Update             2020a-1.el6.noarch                            
Updated     udev-147-2.46.el6.i686                               
Update           147-2.74.el6_10.i686                            
Updated     upstart-0.6.5-12.el6_4.1.i686                        
Update              0.6.5-17.el6.i686                            
Updated     util-linux-ng-2.17.2-12.9.el6_4.3.i686               
Update                    2.17.2-12.28.el6_9.2.i686              
Updated     vim-minimal-2:7.2.411-1.8.el6.i686                   
Update                  2:7.4.629-5.el6_10.2.i686                
Updated     wget-1.12-1.8.el6.i686                               
Update           1.12-10.el6.i686                                
Updated     xz-libs-4.999.9-0.3.beta.20091007git.el6.i686        
Update              4.999.9-0.5.beta.20091007git.el6.i686        
Updated     yum-3.2.29-40.el6.centos.noarch                      
Update          3.2.29-81.el6.centos.0.1.noarch                  
Updated     yum-plugin-fastestmirror-1.1.30-14.el6.noarch        
Update                               1.1.30-42.el6_10.noarch
```

Comment: Or you could just move it to a VM.